# Decoding a very long binary number

Tags: python, decode, decoding

I have a very long binary number (200 digits 0's and 1's long) which I would like to decode. I do not know if this is in Binary 2, Binary 8, Binary 16 or any other (just a long list of 0 and 1)
How can this be decoded (hopefully into some meaningful text)

Is it through some program (say in Python)  or any tools that this could be achieved?

Comment: If you don't know the correct encoding for bytes representing text, the best you can do is guess.

Comment: btw, what is Binary 2, Binary 8, Binary 16?

Comment: powers of Binary 2? =)

Comment: @WasiAhmad - I'm guessing UCS-2, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not a string of ones and zeros, right?  It's really just a collection of bits?  And this is supposed to represent what? Some sort of text?

Answer (score 0):

Wait I didn't think of what TigerhawkT3 mentioned.

Are you talking about UTF-8, UTF-16?

You might be able to use Python codecs module.

"codecs.getreader(encoding)

Look up the codec for the given encoding and return its StreamReader class or factory function.

Raises a LookupError in case the encoding cannot be found."
This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) might help.

Good luck.